# C++ creating new array causing segfault

Tags: c++, arrays, class, memory, segmentation-fault

So I'm having an annoying segfault problem in this function which is supposed to increase the size of an array.

```
void Node::pushArg(Argument arg)
{
    Argument * newlist = new Argument[argc+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        newlist[i] = args[i];
    newlist[argc] = arg;
    delete[] args;
    args = newlist;
    argc++;
}
```

When I run this while using gdb, it tells me my segfault is being caused by this line:

```
Argument * newlist = new Argument[argc+1];
```

I thought it might be a problem with the sizing (# of members vs literal size in bytes) so I tried:

```
Argument * newlist = new Argument[sizeof(Argument)*(argc+1)]
```

But that also causes a segfault in exactly the same way.  Help?

If it's helpful: Here's the definitions for Node and Argument

```
class Argument
{
public:
    bool nested; // is the Argument a string, or a nested Node?
    char * str_content; // string value
    Node * nested_node; // Pointer to nested note

    Argument(); // Null intializer
    Argument(char *); // Create string node 
    Argument(Node *); // Create nested node
    Argument(const Argument&); // Copy constructor
};

class Node
{
public:
    char * head; // Head of list (function)

    int argc; // # of arguments
    Argument * args;

    Node(); //intialize null
    Node(char *); // intialize with head

    void pushArg(Argument); // Add an argument to list

    char * toString(); // the Node in String Format
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `argc`?  Can you construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: argc is initialized to 0 in all the constructors of Node

Comment: Compile with '-g' and post the value of argc (p argc) at the point where it segfaults.  Is there any reason you're not using std::vector?

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to move to std::vector, though I hadn't originally because I was asked to use an array if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that "argc" is a member value, the segfault is likely caused by "this" being an invalid value, probably NULL. You can check this by doing

```
void Node::pushArg(Argument arg)
{
    size_t numArgs = argc + 1;
```

Then look at the value of "this" when that line segfaults.

You should probably also compile with "-Wall -Wextra -O0 -g" to get maximum debugging assistance from your tools.

Comment: Good call, the problem was there was no copy constructor for Node, so when I add a Node to my stack using push_back(), argc was lost, causing a segfault when I tried to create an array of a size > 4 billion :P (or -0249240356 whatever it picks)